# Not able to print Dictionary as DataFrame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have text file contain dictionary, when try to import and print in dataframe in class using pandas it show error as "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!". But when try to import and print in jupyter notebook in cell. It was able to print dataframe. Don't know where it gose wrongs. The dataframe is as follow format.

```
 {'id_1' : {'name': 'person1','height': u'150', 'weight': 56, 'age' : 20, 'DOB' : ''02 Aug 2005'}, 
  'id_2' : {'name': 'person2','height': u'145', 'weight': 50, 'age' : 22, 'DOB' : ''25 Sept 2005'}, 
  'id_3' : {'name': 'person3','height': u'165', 'weight': 65, 'age' : 25, 'DOB' : ''17 May 2004'}}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2):

If parsing from text file I think is necessary first convert strings to dicts by `ast.literal_eval` and then call [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d = """{'id_1' : {'name': 'person1','height': u'150', 'weight': 56, 'age' : 20, 'DOB' : '02 Aug 2005'},
     'id_2' :{'name': 'person2','height': u'145', 'weight': 50, 'age' : 22, 'DOB' : '25 Sept 2005'}, 
     'id_3' : {'name': 'person3','height': u'165', 'weight': 65, 'age' : 25, 'DOB' : '17 May 2004'}}"""
```

---

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ast.literal_eval(d), orient='index')
print (df)
         name height  weight  age           DOB
id_1  person1    150      56   20   02 Aug 2005
id_2  person2    145      50   22  25 Sept 2005
id_3  person3    165      65   25   17 May 2004
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, this code too give error as follows: "ValueError: malformed node or string:"

Comment: @Kedar17 - If use `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')` it working?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like work, since error is different now. Now it show error as : "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'"...